# appropriate mapping to java type for oracle sequence

Tags: java, oracle10g

probably this is a real beginner question, but i cannot find an answer on the web. I have a Oracle db, with a table whose primary key is a NUMBER(16) and is filled with a sequence, whose max value is 999999999999999999999999999 .

what java type should i use to hold the sequence value ? long, biginteger or bigdecimal?

thank you in advance

Comment: Slight problem: `999999999999999999999999999` is too large for a `NUMBER(16)` column.  Perhaps you meant `9999999999999999`?

Comment: no you are right it's too large , unlucky this happens often,  db administrators aren't so smart (or are too lazy), it's still on the development db so we don't waste time to change it yet. Anyway thank you to have point it out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Long should do as it has a maximum value of 2^63 - 1

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, please use scientific notation for large numbers.  It took me a good chunk of time to work out that the number you posted was 10<sup>27</sup>.

If I understand your question correctly, we can *probably* leave the database out of it.  Am I right in thinking that your question boils down to "I need to store positive integers up to 10^27.  What is the smallest data type that will fit this?"

If so, a quick [google](http://www.google.co.uk/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=java+data+types+maximum+values) shows that `long`s will definitely fit.  `BigInteger` and `BigDecimal` will both also definitely contain your number, since they're arbitrary precision, but you don't *need* them, and they'll likely make your code more clunky (due to not being primitives).  So unless you specifically need the Bignum functionality and methods, use `long`.  (And I can't see any reason why you'd use a BigDecimal over BigInteger for inputs that are definitely whole numbers).